# Java jhipster write application log to Log Screen

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster to build micro-services application.I want to confirm that Can I write my application log and view it in the screen below ?

[log screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVljy.png)
Sometime I want to debug or track an action. I'm doing like this:

Ex: `log.debug("Login with username: " + username);`

But it didn't show on the log screen above. Do I have to config something else to show my log on that screen ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't configure this in JHipster, the page you linked is just to view and set logging levels per logger, so you have to code it manually. Aside, your log statement would be better written as `log.debug("Login with username: {}", username);`

Comment: Okie. I deployed app on production so I don't want to open log file to view log by ssh. Maybe I must use GrayLog or ELK stack to view log, right ? Thank you.

Comment: JHipster uses ELK with logstash appender for microservices. The only thing is that an ELK cluster requires some resources, if your project cannot afford them you should consider their cloud offer. Also usually, your hosting solution enables you to see your logs in their dashboard.

Comment: I'm using Google Cloud hosting. I've deployed multiple micro-services in GAE. But Google Logging only show me the request log, not application log. Have you ever used Google Cloud ? I'm finding the way to view application log in GAE but still haven't got any solution.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used it

Comment: okie, thank @GaëlMarziou

Answer (score 1):

The JHipster **Log** screen is improperly named, it is actually about loggers (the mechanism which let's you choose which type of logs you want to show or silence).

What you want is a screen which let's you view the logfile. If your application is deployed to Google Cloud, I think you can use [Stackdriver log viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) to view your logs. You will need to point it to the `/tmp/spring.log` file where your logs are writen.